# What is the method of moments estimator and its asymptotic normality result of the distribution with following density function?

Tags: statistics, density-function

Given following density function $$f(x,\theta) = \frac{1}{3}\theta^{-4} x^7 \exp{-x^2/\theta},$$ I'm calculating the method of moments estimator and its asymptotic normality result. For the method of moments estimator I found $$\hat{\theta}^{\text{MoM}}_n = \left(\frac{32}{35}\right)^2 \frac{\bar{x}}{\pi}.$$ I'm however not entirely sure this is the right answer. Also I have no clue on how to get the asymptotic normality result for this estimator. I'm assuming it has to do with the central limit theorem.

$\textbf{EDIT: }$ Using the CLT I have found this: $$\hat{\theta}^{\text{MoM}}_n \sim \mathcal{N}\left(\frac{32}{35}\sqrt{\theta}, \frac{1}{n}\left( \frac{32^2}{35^2} \frac{5!}{6\sqrt{\pi}} \theta - \theta \sqrt{\pi} \right) \right)$$ but this seems very very messy, making me believe that it is incorrect...

There is a hint given: $$E(X^r) = \frac{1}{6}\Gamma(4 + r/2)θ^{r/2}$$

Comment: It is a [generalised gamma distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generalized_gamma_distribution) but so are many others

Comment: @Henry yes I also found the name! I've updated the question because I can't really find what I'm looking for online...

Comment: So using the link, $E[\bar X] = \frac{\Gamma(9/2)}{\Gamma(8/2)} \sqrt{\theta}$ so your MoM estimate looks correct except with $\bar x ^2$ rather than $\bar x$.  The variance of $\bar X$ is finite so you can use the central limit theorem on $\bar X$ in the usual way and perhaps use something like the Delta method to reverse this for the estimator of $\theta$

Comment: @Henry does that mean that the hint is incorrect? I got my square from the fact that in the hint $\theta$ is to the power $r/2$...

Comment: I have edited my comment.  The hint looks plausible

Comment: @Henry Much appreciated! Would you be able to write down how to get the asymptotic normality?